# how to get component properties through dragStart event in vuejs 2 (i use no libraries )

Tags: vue.js

Im building this draggable tree-view in vuejs 2, without using any library. and on dragstart event i want to get component properties. I tried something like this but i am getting null

```
onDragStart(e){
 const label= e.currentTarget.getAttribute('label')
 console.log(label)
},
```

My node properties on the tree component look like :

```
 <div class="treeviewPannel">
  <tree-node 
  :label="Label" 
  :nodes="Children"
  :children="Children"
  :nodeId="NodeId"
  :isCollapsed="IsCollapsed"
  :isSelected="IsSelected"
  :parent="Parent"
  :iconNode="IconNode"
  :isParent="IsParent"
  :depth="0"
  :draggable="depth>=0"
  :nodeClickedOn="onSelect"
  :expand="onCollapse"
  :dragStart="onDragStart"
  :dragEnter="onDragEnter"
  :dragOver="onDragOver"
  :dragEnd="onDragEnd"
  :dragLeave="onDragLeave"
  :drop="onDrop"></tree-node>
</div>
```

and drag event is on my node component like this :

```
<div class="node"
@drop.prevent.stop="drop"
@dragstart.stop="dragStart"
@dragenter.stop="dragEnter"
@dragover.stop="dragOver"    
@dragleave.stop="dragLeave(label)"
@dragend.stop="dragEnd(label)"
:draggable="depth>=0">
```

and on children part :

```
<div v-if="isCollapsed">   
  <tree-node 
    v-for="(node, index) in nodes"
    :label="node.label"
    :nodes="node.children"
    :children="node.children"
    :isCollapsed="node.isCollapsed"
    :nodeId="node.nodeId"
    :parent="node.parent"
    :isSelected="node.isSelected"
    :depth="depth+1"
    :iconNode="node.iconNode"
    :isParent="node.isParent"
    :expand="expand"
    :nodeClickedOn ="nodeClickedOn"
    :draggable="depth>=0"
    :dragStart="dragStart"
    :dragEnter="dragEnter"
    :dragOver="dragOver"
    :dragLeave="dragLeave"
    :dragEnd="dragEnd"
    :drop="drop"
    class="node-content">
  </tree-node>
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Why not putting a ref on the draggable element and then refer to that $ref on the dragEvent handler to take the properties?